# UIAlertView Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

I have a small doubt. I have a NSObject class where I am trying to display an alert view. So after the alert view is displayed when I tap on OK button I want to push a navigation controller onto the stack. Can I push a navigation controller from general NSObject class? Please let me know guys..thanks for your time..

This is the code..

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{    
  SettingsViewController *homeView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:NO];
    [homeView release];

}
```

I am creating a property called navigationController of type UINavigationController and when I catch the error I am displaying an alert view and I am using above method to push the view controller but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no... depending on how you have your application set up. To push views onto the navigation stack you need to have a **navigation controller**.

Does your NSObject have access to this navigation controller - you might have to set up a delegate method that gets called from your delegate view when the alert view delegate gets called in your NSObject.

I'm just wondering why you're displaying a UIAlertView in an NSObject, why aren't you displaying it in a UIView or a UIViewController?

CustomObject.h

```
@protocol CustomObjectDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)customObjectAlertViewDidClickOk;
@end

@interface CustomObject : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>{
    id<CustomObjectDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CustomObjectDelegate> delegate;
@end;
```

CustomObject.m

```
@synthesize delegate;
// then put this:
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [delegate customObjectAlertViewDidClickOk];
}
```

Then your ViewController .h file needs to include the custom object and assign the delegate methods:

```
#include "CustomObject.h"
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CustomObjectDelegate> {

}
@end
```

and the .m viewDidLoad (or similar):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    CustomObject *obj = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
    [obj setDelegate:self];
}
- (void)customObjectAlertViewDidClickOk{
    AnotherViewController *page = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundles:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:page];
}
```

Thats how I would do it - given I'm not too sure i understand quite what you're asking. :) thats all off the top of my head as well - so don't take it letter for letter, but you have the basis there to start off with. You can build on it. Look up @protocols and delegate methods, its all in there. :)

Comment: thanks for the reply thomas..I am using a service and the service is an NSObject class..so whenever I encounter errors in the service I am displaying alert views..I used alertview's clickedButtonAtIndex method in NSObject class but I am not sure how to push the navigation controller from this method..can you please help me regarding this..if possible can you please post a sample code..

Comment: i'm not to sure what you really mean. You might have to post up some code yourself for me to help you. However I would suggest you just create a delegate method that gts called in `clickedButtonAtIndex`. I will update my post with an example...

Comment: thanks thomas..I will give a try..I included some code..please have a look at it if you have some time..once again thanks for your time